# How to implement data validation in model of MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, validation

I have an MVVM application which requires data validation. I would like to keep the validation in the model, so the model can be easily reused with other view models without having to duplicate the validation code. Most examples of data validation with WPF either have the validation done in the view model in a MVVM setup, or data validation done in the model when the model is directly bound to the view and a view model is not used.

I would like to have the data validation in my model, have the view model expose my model to the view, and have the view still be able to receive validation feedback from the model. I am planning on either using IDataErrorInfo or Data Annotations for my validation. I have found some examples of this being done, but neither approach seems ideal.

It is accomplished [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22660.data-validation-in-mvvm.aspx) with Data Annotations, though it took a moderate amount of custom code.

I like [this](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/7/2/simple-validation-in-wpf-mvvm-using-idataerrorinfo) approach with IDataErrorInfo better as it does not involve custom code, however I don't know if I am comfortable with the approach taken, where the entire model is exposed as a single property to the view, versus exposing just the required individual properties.

Is there a better or more recommended way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data annotations method you've linked is somewhat redundant as the framework already has the concept of bindable validation rules (see [*Taking data binding, validation and MVVM to the next level*](http://techfilth.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/taking-databinding-validation-and-mvvm.html)). The only time the data annotations approach will be useful is when validating in a spot that is completely divorced from the UI.

Aside from those two options, using IDataErrorInfo is your only other choice. Note that you are not *"exposing the entire model to the view as a single property"*, rather you are using an interface to expose your custom entity to the binding framework - there's a big difference. If you choose this method then make sure you use resource strings to hold your error messages rather than using hard coded text. The IDataErrorInfo approach is useful if you have different people working on the view and viewmodel - the person doing the view doesn't need to know anything about the specific validations of the viewmodel.

Comment: Ok, I have seen IDataErrorInfo used a lot, but most examples the IDataErrorInfo interface is implemented by the view model, or in a non-MVVM WPF app, in the model which is directly bound to the view. The link I referenced is one of the few places I have seen them use IDataErrorInfo at the model, and then still use the view model to expose model to the view. Being uncommon in that regard, do you feel it is still a "proper" approach?

Comment: As I'm sure you'd appreciate, there are levels of "proper". I don't like exposing the model directly to the view - yet nobody thinks twice when they have an ObservableCollection of models in the viewmodel and then bind a list type UI element to that ObservableCollection (ideally (in a perfect world) each of those models in the collection should have been wrapped in a viewmodel object). MVVM doesn't say that you *shouldn't* bind directly to a model object, it simply stipulates a pattern to best abstract the view from the viewmodel and models. There will always be compromises.

Comment: I understand. So if I inisist on wanting validation done at my model, and am in a MVVM project, I guess using IDataErrorInfo at the model, and then using the view model to expose that model to the view is the only approach, right? I considered ValidationRules (including BindingGroups) and validating on exceptions, but both of those would require validation to be done outside of the model, either in the view model's properties for validating on exceptions, or in a separate class for ValidationRules.

Comment: Yep, that's right. You could go for a bit of a hybrid approach and implement IDataErrorInfo on the VM as well, and as part of that implementation you call the IDEI implementation on the model, so that the VM is acting as a proper adapter/abstracter. It's really your call in deciding how practical it is to be as perfect as possible with the pattern - sometimes being strict and perfect is counter productive.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help! I would upvote your answer but don't have the needed 15 reputation yet.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up avoiding the `IDataErrorInfo` stuff as it was a royal pain to use. We placed our validation on the models, using attributes.

```
public class User : ValidatableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string password = string.Empty;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [ValidateObjectHasValue(
        FailureMessage = "E-Mail can not be left blank.", 
        ValidationMessageType = typeof(ValidationErrorMessage))]
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return this.email;
        }

        set
        {
            this.email = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }

    [ValidateStringIsGreaterThan(
        GreaterThanValue = 6, 
        ValidateIfMemberValueIsValid = "Email",  
        FailureMessage = "Password must be greater than 6 characters.", 
        ValidationMessageType = typeof(ValidationErrorMessage))]
    [ValidateStringIsLessThan(
        LessThanValue = 20, 
        ValidateIfMemberValueIsValid = "Email", 
        FailureMessage = "Password must be less than 20 characters.", 
        ValidationMessageType = typeof(ValidationErrorMessage))]
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return this.password;
        }

        set
        {
            this.password = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, validation is performed to make sure that the email property is not empty, and the password validation does a range check. The password validation does not fire until the `Email` property is considered to be in a valid state.

The [validation project is hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/scionwest/ValidatableBase) and supports a wide-range of things.

1. Custom Validation Delegates
2. Intercepting validation results in custom delegates
3. Localized validation failure messages
4. INotifyPropertyChanged support
5. Validation of all properties in 1 method call
6. Validate individual Properties as needed.
7. Requery validation on the entire model, or per-property as needed.
8. Validation injection from a view model
9. Validation proxy's. (Perform validation and pass the results to a proxy).
10. Validate based on the result of another property. Nested properties are supported.
11. Conditionally validate based on the state of other properties.
12. Easily templated, so you can have validation warnings, info and errors.

I've used this in several projects and it works nice. A real big benefit i've gotten from is that I can re-use validation rules across multiple objects now (IDataErrorInfo suffers from a lot of copy/paste) and I can create DataTemplates around what kind of Validation Message the rules provide back. We've got templates for warnings and templates for errors. Gives you a lot of flexibility.

The original intent of the project was to use it for WinRT projects, but it quickly grew in to something I use on my mobile *and* WPF apps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do all validation in the model, and that is the purpose of the ViewModel.

The reason is that in the View you'll probably have some text boxes that bind their Text property to numbers, dates and other data types that are not directly assignable from a string.

If the user clears the box, or is part way through entering a value (maybe they start a number with a minus sign or decimal point, or are editing a date) the TextBox.Text cannot be converted to the right type for WPF to send to the model. So the model is not updated - it still has its old value and thinks that it is valid. If the user hits the Save button, it will save the last valid value, not what is on the screen.

Unless you restrict your UI to controls that are always valid (checkboxes, listboxes, etc) you need a view model to validate values before you can pass them to the model.